# How to automate FGDC metadata generation in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, metadata, united-states

Does anyone know of a tool or script to automate FGDC standard metadata for ArcGIS?  I would like to be able to select multiple feature classes and fill company info., dates, etc.

Comment: What version of arcgis are you using? I have made a python script to do this in 10.1, with the loss of the 9.3 FGDC editor.

Comment: If you are familiar with python, you could use the [xml.etree.elementtree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) in a tool to fill in fields of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

In case if you will not find any easy solution here is one possible python way:

1. Export metadata to XML file using [Export Metadata (Conversion)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Export_Metadata/00120000000t000000/) tool.
2. Modify metadata in XML file. There are many solutions for this task in Python. For example, you can use [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).
3. Import metadata from XML to your featureclass using [Import Metadata (Conversion)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Import_Metadata/00120000000w000000/) tool.